# Ubuntu SSHFS doesn't sync

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, scp, sshfs, ubuntu-12.10

I am trying to set up a Ubuntu-machine for web development, and thought i'd start working with SSHFS instead of the annoying FTP-protocol. I installed SSHFS through apt-get. I've created a folder in my documents folder called `MyProject`. I'm the owner of that folder.

I mount the remote folder to my local folder using

```
sshfs root@myproject.com:ftp.myproject.com/myproject.com/public_html /home/anton/Documents/MyProject
```

Followed by my password.
Then the remote folder is indeed mounted. However, the changes i make on my local computer is not reflected on the server. What am i missing here?

Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: why nobody answers this??

Answer (score 10):

Add `-o cache=no` to the command

```
sshfs root@myproject.com:ftp.myproject.com/myproject.com/public_html /home/anton/Documents/MyProject -o cache=no
```

The same has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671350/any-way-to-eliminate-time-lag-with-sshfs

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as @op but in more complex version - I mount root folder of remote device, and most importantly need to operate with remote **sysfs**.

The answer from @Vikas helped me but not completely. I tried adding mount options:  **sshfs_sync,sync_readdir,sync_read** but none of that resolved my problem: sometimes (rather often) reads from the same path were still cached and thus I couldn't get the changed state on remote side. I guess this is because fs in this case (when sysfs entries are provided by kernel drivers) is unable to provide meaningful change/modification time. And fuse/sshfs on local side rely on these.

The only one option resolved my problem - **direct_io**. So, I recommend this option instead in case of remote sysfs is used and where synchronization is top priority.

```
sshfs <remote> <local> -o direct_io
```

Comment: This did not work for me